# angular "ngModel" TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following `ngModel` in my Angular app.

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="structuresInfo.structures_elements.se_element_setting[i]['setting_id']" type="text" name="playVoice_i" >
```

Note that input is inside a `ngFor` and `i` can be from 0 to any number. How can I define the `structuresInfo` in the component?

I have the following:

```
interface element_setting {
    setting_id,
    setting_value
}
interface settings {
    se_element_setting: element_setting[]
}
...
structuresInfo:any = { 
    structures: {},
    structures_elements:<settings> {
    }
};
```

But I still get the error. Here is the **error message**:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: `structuresInfo.structures_elements.se_element_setting` is **`undefinied`**.

Comment: So, how should I initial the property?

Comment: initialize structures_elements as empty array

Comment: what is the array you are iterating in template?

Answer (score 0):

You must initilize it as an empty array or you have to check is it undefined or not.

```
interface element_setting {
    setting_id,
    setting_value
}
class settings {
    se_element_setting: element_setting[];
    constructor(){
       this.se_element_setting = [];
    }
}
...
structuresInfo:any = { 
    structures: {},
    structures_elements:<settings> {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

structuresInfo.structures_elements.se_element_setting is not set from start. 
It could typically be because your getting it from the server. So either make sure it's initialized to [] OR you could add a:

```
<ng-content *ngIf="structuresInfo.structures_elements.se_element_setting">
...your ngFor
</ng-content>
```